# C#: "Pretty" type name function?

Tags: c#, generics, types, pretty-print

The name properties of System.Type class return a strange result in case of generic types. Is there a way to get the type name in a format closer to the way I specified it?
Example: `typeof(List<string>).OriginalName == "List<string>"`

Comment: This is pretty easy to write yourself as an extension method using recursion.

Comment: Such function is not in the framework, because it depends on the language you use: VB has different representation of generics and I'm sure other languages too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood, that I have to write this myself. Here is my solution (it is actually a bit more than asked for). It is, probably, helpfull.

```
using System.Reflection;
using HWClassLibrary.Debug;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace HWClassLibrary.Helper
{
    public static class TypeNameExtender
    {
        private static IEnumerable<Type> _referencedTypesCache;

        public static void OnModuleLoaded() { _referencedTypesCache = null; }

        public static string PrettyName(this Type type)
        {
            if(type == typeof(int))
                return "int";
            if(type == typeof(string))
                return "string";

            var result = PrettyTypeName(type);
            if(type.IsGenericType)
                result = result + PrettyNameForGeneric(type.GetGenericArguments());
            return result;
        }

        private static string PrettyTypeName(Type type)
        {
            var result = type.Name;
            if(type.IsGenericType)
                result = result.Remove(result.IndexOf('`'));

            if (type.IsNested && !type.IsGenericParameter)
                return type.DeclaringType.PrettyName() + "." + result;

            if(type.Namespace == null)
                return result;

            var conflictingTypes = ReferencedTypes
                .Where(definedType => definedType.Name == type.Name && definedType.Namespace != type.Namespace)
                .ToArray();

            var namespaceParts = type.Namespace.Split('.').Reverse().ToArray();
            var namespacePart = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < namespaceParts.Length && conflictingTypes.Length > 0; i++)
            {
                namespacePart = namespaceParts[i] + "." + namespacePart;
                conflictingTypes = conflictingTypes
                    .Where(conflictingType => (conflictingType.Namespace + ".").EndsWith(namespacePart))
                    .ToArray();
            }

            return namespacePart + result;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Type> ReferencedTypes
        {
            get
            {
                if(_referencedTypesCache == null)
                    _referencedTypesCache = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedTypes();
                return _referencedTypesCache;
            }
        }

        private static string PrettyNameForGeneric(Type[] types)
        {
            var result = "";
            var delim = "<";
            foreach(var t in types)
            {
                result += delim;
                delim = ",";
                result += t.PrettyName();
            }
            return result + ">";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

The problem with "pretty" names is they are different depending on the language you are using. Imagine the surprise of a VB.NET developer if `OriginalName` returned C# syntax.

However, it's pretty fairly easy to make this yourself:

```
private static string PrettyName(Type type)
{
    if (type.GetGenericArguments().Length == 0)
    {
        return type.Name;
    }
    var genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
    var typeDefinition = type.Name;
    var unmangledName = typeDefinition.Substring(0, typeDefinition.IndexOf("`"));
    return unmangledName + "<" + String.Join(",", genericArguments.Select(PrettyName)) + ">";
}
```

This will recursively resolve the unmanaged name, so that if you have something like `Dictionary<string, IList<string>>` it should still work.

Comment: Ideally this needs further development to handle types like `Dictionary<string,IList<string>>.KeyCollection`. Its CLR type name is `Dictionary\`2+KeyCollection[System.String,IList\`1[System.String]]` (give or take namespace qualifiers). Furthermore you can have things like `Outer\`1+Inner\`1[OuterArg,InnerArg]`. And of course you can have arrays (1D 2D etc.) and pointers to a generic type, which need handling. :)

Answer (score 21):

I used `CodeDomProvider` to convert to c#:

```
    public static string GetOriginalName(this Type type)
    {
        string TypeName = type.FullName.Replace(type.Namespace + ".", "");//Removing the namespace

        var provider = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"); //You can also use "VisualBasic"
        var reference = new System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(TypeName);

        return provider.GetTypeOutput(reference);
    }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to leave out namespaces?

Comment: You could use type.Name instead of the type.FullName I guess so you don't have to remove the namespace yourself. Sorry, I see now you don't get the generic parameters that way.

Answer (score 3):

Like Harold Hoyer's answer but including nullables and a few more built-in types:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get full type name with full namespace names
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">
/// The type to get the C# name for (may be a generic type or a nullable type).
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// Full type name, fully qualified namespaces
/// </returns>
public static string CSharpName(this Type type)
{
    Type nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    string nullableText;
    if (nullableType != null)
    {
        type = nullableType;
        nullableText = "?";
    }
    else
    {
        nullableText = string.Empty;
    }

    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        return string.Format(
            "{0}<{1}>{2}", 
            type.Name.Substring(0, type.Name.IndexOf('`')), 
            string.Join(", ", type.GetGenericArguments().Select(ga => ga.CSharpName())), 
            nullableText);
    }

    switch (type.Name)
    {
        case "String":
            return "string";
        case "Int32":
            return "int" + nullableText;
        case "Decimal":
            return "decimal" + nullableText;
        case "Object":
            return "object" + nullableText;
        case "Void":
            return "void" + nullableText;
        default:
            return (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.FullName) ? type.Name : type.FullName) + nullableText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my implementation. It was created to describe methods, so it handles the `ref` and `out` keywords.

```
private static Dictionary<Type, string> shorthandMap = new Dictionary<Type, string>
{
    { typeof(Boolean), "bool" },
    { typeof(Byte), "byte" },
    { typeof(Char), "char" },
    { typeof(Decimal), "decimal" },
    { typeof(Double), "double" },
    { typeof(Single), "float" },
    { typeof(Int32), "int" },
    { typeof(Int64), "long" },
    { typeof(SByte), "sbyte" },
    { typeof(Int16), "short" },
    { typeof(String), "string" },
    { typeof(UInt32), "uint" },
    { typeof(UInt64), "ulong" },
    { typeof(UInt16), "ushort" },
};

private static string CSharpTypeName(Type type, bool isOut = false)
{
    if (type.IsByRef)
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", isOut ? "out" : "ref", CSharpTypeName(type.GetElementType()));
    }
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            return String.Format("{0}?", CSharpTypeName(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)));
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Format("{0}<{1}>", type.Name.Split('`')[0],
                String.Join(", ", type.GenericTypeArguments.Select(a => CSharpTypeName(a)).ToArray()));
        }
    }
    if (type.IsArray)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}[]", CSharpTypeName(type.GetElementType()));
    }

    return shorthandMap.ContainsKey(type) ? shorthandMap[type] : type.Name;
}
```

The calling code looks like this:

```
string line = String.Format("{0}.{1}({2})",
    method.DeclaringType.Name,
    method.Name,
    String.Join(", ", method.GetParameters().Select(p => CSharpTypeName(p.ParameterType, p.IsOut) + " " + p.Name).ToArray()));
```

Where `method` is a `MethodInfo` instance.

One note: I didn't have a need to describe any multi-dimensional array types, so I didn't bother implementing description for that, but it would be fairly easy to add by calling `type.GetArrayRank()`.

Answer (score 3):

A minimal work solution that leverages `CodeDomProvider` is to control how the `CodeTypeReference` instance is built in the first place. There are special cases only for generic types and multi-rank arrays, so we only have to care about those:

```
static CodeTypeReference CreateTypeReference(Type type)
{
    var typeName = (type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(string)) ? type.FullName : type.Name;
    var reference = new CodeTypeReference(typeName);
    if (type.IsArray)
    {
        reference.ArrayElementType = CreateTypeReference(type.GetElementType());
        reference.ArrayRank = type.GetArrayRank();
    }

    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        foreach (var argument in type.GetGenericArguments())
        {
            reference.TypeArguments.Add(CreateTypeReference(argument));
        }
    }
    return reference;
}
```

Using this modified factory method, it is then possible to use the appropriate code provider to get pretty typing, like so:

```
using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
{
    var reference = CreateTypeReference(typeof(IObservable<IEnumerable<Tuple<int?, string>>>[,]));
    var output = provider.GetTypeOutput(reference);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

The above code returns `IObservable<IEnumerable<Tuple<Nullable<int>, string>>>[,]`. The only special case that is not handled well are `Nullable` types but this is really more a fault of the `CodeDomProvider` than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write this yourself. Keep in mind that `Type.Name` etc. are invoking methods that live in the CLR and can be invoked from multiple languages. This is why they don't come back looking like C# or VB or the language the caller was coded in, but instead looking like the CLR representation.

Note further that `string` and what not are aliases for CLR types like `System.String`. Again, this plays a role in the formatting that you see.

It's not hard to do using reflection, but I question the value of it.

Answer (score 1):

First: Kudos to Navid for wheel reinvention avoidance.  I would upvote if I could.

Here are a few points to add, if anyone goes down this path (at least for VS10/.Net 4):
* Try using one of the variants of CodeTypeReference with Type arguments.  This avoids a number of pitfalls of using string type names (such as trailing &) and means you get back `bool` instead of `System.Boolean` etc.  You do get back the full namespace for a lot of types like this but you can always get rid of the namespace part later.
* Simple Nullables tend to come back in the form `System.Nullable<int>` rather than `int?` - You can convert to the nicer syntax with a regex on the answer such as:
`const string NullablePattern = @"System.Nullable<(?<nulledType>[\w\.]+)>";
const string NullableReplacement = @"${nulledType}?";
answer = Regex.Replace(answer, NullablePattern, NullableReplacement);`
* The Type of a method argument like `out T?` gives a very opaque string. If anyone has an elegant way of dealing with things like this I would love to know about it.
Hopefully this all becomes very easy with Roslyn.

Comment: Sorry, Nullable pattern was scrambled.  Should be <code>@"System\.Nullable<(?<nulledType>[\w\.]+)>";</code>

Answer (score 0):

as in your example you can expect the type so you can try that

```
public class test<T> where T : class
{
    public List<String> tt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
 ///////////////////////////
 test<List<String>> tt = new  test<List<String>>();
if(tt.GetType().FullName.Contains(TypeOf(List<String>).FullName))
{
   //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to compare types.
The best way to do this is...
`myVar is List<string>` or
`myVar.GetType() == myOtherVar.GetType()`

If you don't need this... please disregard my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this ..

```
public static class TypeExtensions {
    public static String GetName(this Type t) {
        String readable;

#if PREVENT_RECURSION
        if(m_names.TryGetValue(t, out readable)) {
            return readable;
        }
#endif

        var tArgs = t.IsGenericType ? t.GetGenericArguments() : Type.EmptyTypes;
        var name = t.Name;
        var format = Regex.Replace(name, @"`\d+.*", "")+(t.IsGenericType ? "<?>" : "");
        var names = tArgs.Select(x => x.IsGenericParameter ? "" : GetName(x));
        readable=String.Join(String.Join(",", names), format.Split('?'));

#if PREVENT_RECURSION
        m_names.Add(t, readable);
#endif

        return readable;
    }

    static readonly Dictionary<Type, String> m_names = new Dictionary<Type, String> { };
}
```

where `PREVENT_RECURSION` should be defined `true` if you don't want the type in generic type arguments be resolved recursively every time, just take from the cache dictionary; leave it undefined of false if you don't care that.

Answer (score 0):

Combined a few answers, added support for nested types and array ranks, and turned it into an extension method with cached resolved names.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension methods for <see cref="Type"/>.
/// </summary>
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary of type names.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string> typeNames;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="TypeExtensions"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    static TypeExtensions()
    {
        typeNames = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string>
                        {
                            [typeof(bool)] = "bool",
                            [typeof(byte)] = "byte",
                            [typeof(char)] = "char",
                            [typeof(decimal)] = "decimal",
                            [typeof(double)] = "double",
                            [typeof(float)] = "float",
                            [typeof(int)] = "int",
                            [typeof(long)] = "long",
                            [typeof(sbyte)] = "sbyte",
                            [typeof(short)] = "short",
                            [typeof(string)] = "string",
                            [typeof(uint)] = "uint",
                            [typeof(ulong)] = "ulong",
                            [typeof(ushort)] = "ushort"
                        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type name with generics and array ranks resolved.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">
    /// The type whose name to resolve.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The resolved type name.
    /// </returns>
    public static string ToCSTypeName(this Type type)
    {
        return typeNames.GetOrAdd(type, GetPrettyTypeName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type name as it would be written in C#
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">
    /// The type whose name is to be written.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The type name as it is written in C#
    /// </returns>
    private static string GetPrettyTypeName(Type type)
    {
        var typeNamespace = type.DeclaringType != null ? ToCSTypeName(type.DeclaringType) : type.Namespace;
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                return $"{ToCSTypeName(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type))}?";
            }

            var typeList = string.Join(", ", type.GenericTypeArguments.Select(ToCSTypeName).ToArray());
            var typeName = type.Name.Split('`')[0];

            return $"{typeNamespace}.{typeName}<{typeList}>";
        }

        if (type.IsArray)
        {
            var arrayRank = string.Empty.PadLeft(type.GetArrayRank() - 1, ',');
            var elementType = ToCSTypeName(type.GetElementType());
            return $"{elementType}[{arrayRank}]";
        }

        return $"{typeNamespace}.{type.Name}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string pretty_name( Type type, int recursion_level = -1, bool expand_nullable = false )
{
    if( type.IsArray )
    {
        return $"{pretty_name( type.GetElementType(), recursion_level, expand_nullable )}[]";
    }

    if( type.IsGenericType )
    {
        // find generic type name
        var gen_type_name = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name;
        var index = gen_type_name.IndexOf( '`' );
        if( index != -1 )
            gen_type_name = gen_type_name.Substring( 0, index );

        // retrieve generic type aguments
        var arg_names = new List<string>();
        var gen_type_args = type.GetGenericArguments();
        foreach( var gen_type_arg in gen_type_args )
        {
            arg_names.Add(
                recursion_level != 0
                    ? pretty_name( gen_type_arg, recursion_level - 1, expand_nullable )
                    : "?" );
        }

        // if type is nullable and want compact notation '?'
        if( !expand_nullable && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType( type ) != null )
            return $"{arg_names[ 0 ]}?";

        // compose common generic type format "T<T1, T2, ...>"
        return $"{gen_type_name}<{string.Join( ", ", arg_names )}>";
    }

    return type.Name;
}
```

My two cents:

- Everything is done through the Type interface
- No Regex
- No extra objects created except for the list that holds generic argument names
- Supports infinite recursion or recursion to a certain level (or no recursion at all!)
- Supports nullable types (both formats "Nullable<>" and "?")
- Supports ranked arrays